# Any faster way to determine how far away the points from a point, line, and polygon?

Tags: python, algorithm, distance, point, shapely

I'm trying to make a code that calculates the distance between a set of points from a set of point / line / polygon.

Code below with the sample data gives me data but it is taking forever to go through all the points (Around an hour or so)

I am using shapely because it should also include distance between:

1. point - point
2. point - line segment
3. point - polygon
   Line segments and polygons are not included in the code

Is it because I am using for loop?

Is there more efficient way of achieving this?

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time
start = timer()
import numpy as np
import shapely
import progressbar
from shapely.geometry import Point

#Create 10k Random X and Y coordinates
x_coordinates=np.random.rand(10000)
y_coordinates=np.random.rand(10000)

#Create 40k Center points of Circles
Circles=np.ones((201*201,2),dtype=float)
linspace=np.linspace(-1, 1, num=201) #set distance between circles for sample data. Actual data are more randomly placed and changes from design to design
temp=0

#Make array of circles
for x in linspace:
    Circles[temp:temp+201,0]=x
    Circles[temp:temp+201,1]=linspace
    temp=temp+201

#Create empty array for saving result
#result should save which circle the point belongs
result=np.empty([10000, 2], dtype=object)

for x in progressbar.progressbar(range(10000)):
    defect = Point(x_coordinates[x],y_coordinates[x]) #go through 10000 points
    for j in range(201*201):
        if defect.distance(Point(Circles[j,:]))<0.005: #go through 40000 circles
            result[x]=Circles[j,:]
            break #break if match found
        
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to reduce the complexity by [hidden surface removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-surface_determination) and [bounding volumes and spatial partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph#Scene_graphs_and_bounding_volume_hierarchies_(BVHs))? What do you need this data for?

Comment: Basically, all the polygons, lines and points represents features on my pcb sample. 
This pcb is Inspected via automatic optical inspection system, and outputs coordinates of defects into certain format.
What I am trying to do is to figure out which feature the defect belongs to.
Each lines represents fine pattern on pcb circuit, and point represents circular pads.

Comment: And the closest is the most likely, like clustering? I would think hierarchical bounding volumes would get the least code / speedup. Both on pcb and features. I know that there's also quite a savings having a stochastic element of quality control, but may not apply in this case. Also, offloading it to the GPU may be good.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with numpy (or shapely) but based on your code you are looking for circles that are close to your points. Slightly confused about why you have circles at all based on the title of the question. (Is there any need for circles in your code as they seem to be only used as points anyway?)

> distance between a set of points from a set of point

Do you need the distance for each point to each of your circles? What is it that you are specifically looking for?

Your algorithm is slow for two reasons:

1. Calculate distance between two points. This is a straight forward calculation but involves taking a square root which is slow compared to other operations.
   Instead use the square of the distance. Use the formula for the distance but just skip the square root. Maybe this isn't too slow in shapely.
2. Comparing each point with possibly EVERY circle by calculating the distance. This is most likely the main cause of your code being slow.
   If you don't need the distance from each point to all the circles then you need a fast way to find the circle you are looking for. You could consider ordering your circles by the x-coordinates to achieve this. Based on your code looking for circles very close (`0.005`) to your point, you could easily eliminate all circles whose x-coordinate is further than that from your point and completely skip calculating the distance between the two. (Then you could do the same for the y-coordinates.) This way you wouldn't need to look at all the circles but could jump out of that loop because you know the rest is going to be further away on that axis.

If you provide a better description of what exactly you are looking for then someone can probably provide an example of how you could implement it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I've removed the square root for now.
Also I'll try to reduce the load by sorting them into x-coordinate, and filtering each components into certain range prior to calculation. 

Better description of what I am doing: 
I have bunch of samples with different design, and coordinate of defect location
I am trying to figure out which objects (Circles, Lines, Polygon) defect belongs to